# Combine css external links to one link

Tags: jquery, css, sass

i am trying to add up all the css link to one. So it helps to load the page much quicker.

the links i am using are:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_files/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index_files/goStyle.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index_files/jquerylogin.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/index_files/jquery-ui.css">
```

As of research, suggestion are to combine all the css to one file, but i am having problem with same class name affecting different label.

I tried adding the link like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_files/stylesheet.css+goStyle.css+jquerylogin.css+jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
```

But no luck.

Please somebody help me with this.

Comment: Unless your css files are gigantic or your hosting server is exceptionally slow, it is unlikely that combining the stylesheets will have the payoff you're expecting. If caching is properly set up, the page load should be 0 after the initial visit.

Comment: The performance benefits you're asking for aren't a product of the number of links involved, but the number of files being requested.  If you want to have only 1 HTTP request, then you have to serve only 1 file to the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine and Minify Multiple CSS / JS Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use CSS Import Rules

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/Combined.css" />
```

Combined Css Inside you can import all other css like below

```
@import url('/css/s1.css');
@import url('/css/s2.css');
@import url('/css/s3.css');
```

for more information read below article

http://www.cssnewbie.com/css-import-rule/#.U2CN9Pk70dE

Comment: This won't accomplish what the OP is asking for.  This still makes the same number of HTTP requests, but has worse performance (see: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/).

Answer (score 0):

Please read this page: [Combine and Minify Multiple CSS / JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files)

> Check out minify - it allows you combine multiple js, css files into
>   one just by stacking them into a url, e.g.
>
> `<script src="/scripts/js/main.js,/scripts/js/adapter/adapter.js"></script>`
>
> We've used it for years and it does a great job and does it on the fly
>   (no need to edit files).

Comment: Yes, you should do. Provided library is used for js and css

Answer (score 0):

If you combine all CSS into one CSS in same sequence, it will have same effect like including separately.

Combine all the CSS files in same sequence like :

```
/* stylesheet.css */

/*### stylesheet CSS Goes Here ###*/

/* goStyle.css */

/*### goStyle CSS Goes Here ###*/

/* jquerylogin.css */

/*### jquerylogin CSS Goes Here ###*/

/* jquery-ui */

/*### jquery-ui CSS Goes Here ###*/
```