# How to bundle JavaScript files in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, bundler, webstorm, combiners

How to combine 2 or more JavaScript files in to a one file in PhpStorm (OR WebStorm).

I've searched and found just this result but it is not an answer:
[Minifying JavaScript](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/minifying-javascript.html?search=combine%20javascript)

I want something like this: [Visual studio Bundler & Minifier plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in feature for that in IDE.
You can configure a grunt task inside IDE to concatenate files with https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat
See also: [Combine multiple JavaScript files into one JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511989/combine-multiple-javascript-files-into-one-js-file) and 
[Combine and Minify Multiple CSS / JS Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287823/combine-and-minify-multiple-css-js-files)

Comment: is not best answer becuse phpstrom is not best IDE. tnx. i use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat